# how use an OR in C# linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
var pairs = from car in A 
        from truck in B 
        where car.color.Contains(search) ||OR car.brand.Contains(search)
        select new {car, truck};
```

I need to search my database with an OR in my LINQ I don't know what the correct syntax would be.

Comment: See here: [Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations#filtering)

Comment: You  already answered your question in your post. For OR operator use ||